# Given $A^2 = AB$ and $B^2=I+BA$, prove that $A=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$A,B$ are a $n\times n$ matrices. given that

> $A^2 = AB$ and $B^2=I+BA$

Prove that $A=0$.

Is the following proof correct?

If we write $A^2=AB \rightarrow A^2-AB=0 \rightarrow A(A-B)=0$

We get that $A$ or $(A-B)$ equals $0$.

We then write $B^2 = I+BA \rightarrow B^2 -BA = I \rightarrow B(B-A)=I$
and we get that $B^{-1}=(B-A)$

Now, since $-B^{-1}=-(B-A)=(A-B)$

And that $B(-B^{-1})=-(BB^{-1})=-I$ we get that $(A-B) \neq 0$ which means $A=0$

Comment: No. The product of matrices can be zero without either of the factors being zero

Comment: The product of two nonzero matrices can be zero. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^2$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$\tag1A^2=AB$$
and $$\tag2B^2=I+BA$$
imply
$$A^3\stackrel{(1)}=A^2B\stackrel{(1)}=AB^2\stackrel{(2)}=A(I+BA)=A+ABA\stackrel{(1)}=A+A^3$$
so that $A=0$.
Apparently, the conclusion is valid in *any* ring,  not just for matrices.

---

Nevertheless, your proof is nicely savable, even in spit of the major blunder where you say that one of the factors has to be zero:
You show correctly that $B(B-A)=I$, hence $B-A$ is invertible, hence so is $A-B$, hence $0=A(A-B)$ *does* imply that $A=0$ (namely, by multiplying with $(A-B)^{-1}$ from the right; you even elaborate that $(A-B)^{-1}=-B$. I am however certain that the mentioned blunder *will* lead to severe point deduction.

Comment: Well I'll take a severe points deduction than getting a zero so at least I have that I guess

Answer (score 2):

For matrices, you cannot conclude that $ST = 0$ implies at least one of $S$ and $T$ is the zero matrix in general (cf the example by player3236 in the comments). So that part isn't quite right though the rest seems okay to me. That said, the last bit is a bit clunky. I'd write it as $A(A-B) = 0$ however $(A-B)$ is invertible per the above and multiplying on the right on both sides by its inverse leads to $A = 0$.

Comment: Well that sucks, this was my test answer :/ do you think this mistake will lead to 0 points on the answer?

Comment: If I was the one grading your solution? No. If it was a 10 point problem, you'd get at least an 8 from me. I'd dock a point for the wrong conclusion for $ST = 0$ implying at least one of $S$ and $T$ is zero. I might dock you a point for the awkwardness of the solution at the bottom (not explicitly mentioning $B(B-A) = I$).

Comment: Well that's a bit comforting, thank you, I hope the guy grading my test would think the same as you